# drupal: how to have select list as a field draw from a content type?

Tags: select, drupal-7, field, content-type

I have a content type buildings and one called rooms. There are multiple rooms per building. I have a form for room and I want to have a list the user can choose from that is a list of the buildings, that is generated from the list of buildings.

How?

The only type of list I see is tags and I want this automated, not manually add to the list or tags.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have two content type, Building and Room.

You can download a module "EntityReference", then add an entity reference field to Building, ex. field_building_rooms, where you can select room as content type for the widget. Since the field allow you to add single or multiple value, you can have as many as rooms for one building.

This way, when you try to add a new Building, it'll allow you to choose single/multiple rooms to it as well.